# how can i save object in mobille storage using react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am building an application in which I want to save user data. and user able to see that data later. I am using `AsyncStorage`.. i want to store multiple values in one key. I used `AsyncStorage.setItem.`. here is my code..

```
var obj ={
       name : "sabih",
       color : "blue"
}
AsyncStorage.setItem('myKey', JSON.stringify(obj))
     .then(() => {
         console.log('data saved')
})
```

but when i get data with AsyncStorage.getItem. it gives me like this

`{"name":"sabih" , "color" : "blue"}`

**Code here**

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("myKey").then((data) => {
   var userData = JSON.parse(data)
      console.log(userData, 'Get Values')
}).done();
```

How can i set name's and color's value in state. or how can i render these values in my react native application..

Thanks in advance.
and please attach a snap of solution if possible..

Comment: Can you please explain some more ? What do you want to do exactly so that we can help you out.

Comment: i want to show data to user which is stored in mobile. @AkshayRao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function inside your file and call that function passing your asyncstrorage value as parameter as below :-

```
_renderDetail=(item)=>{
   this.setState({user:item});
}
```

and inside your asyncStorage code edit as :-

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("myKey").then((data) => {
   var userData = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log(userData, 'Get Values');
   this._renderDetail(userData);
}).done();
```

and then you can use this state variables inside your render function as :-

```
<Text>{this.state.user.name}</Text>
<Text>{this.state.user.color}</Text>
```